# React.js running yarn start results in error

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

When I run `yarn start` which is just a wrapper for `webpack-dev-server index.js` results in this error:

```
yarn run v1.12.1
$ webpack-dev-server index.js
C:\react-tut\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:363
    throw err;
    ^


TypeError: Cannot destructure property `compile` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
    at addHooks (C:\react-tut\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js:114:49)

at new Server (C:\react-tut\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\lib\Server.js:127:5)

at startDevServer (C:\react-tut\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:355:14)

at portfinder.getPort (C:\react-tut\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\bin\webpack-dev-server.js:323:5)

at C:\react-tut\node_modules\portfinder\lib\portfinder.js:190:16
at C:\react-tut\node_modules\portfinder\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:52:16
at C:\react-tut\node_modules\portfinder\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:269:32

at C:\react-tut\node_modules\portfinder\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:44:16
at C:\react-tut\node_modules\portfinder\lib\portfinder.js:151:16
at Server.onListen (C:\react-tut\node_modules\portfinder\lib\portfinder.js:43:7)
```

And really I'm not sure what's going on as I was just following a tutorial about setting up React with yarn.

Comment: What's the version of webpack-dev-server you using?

Comment: "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"

Comment: What Tutorial were you following?

Comment: https://codeburst.io/yet-another-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-a-react-project-part-1-bdc8a29aea22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

webpack-dev-server 3.x is only compatible with webpack 4.x. So I would recommend you to downgrade it to webpack-dev-server 2.x like v2.11.1. Check this [github issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1334) or [Github issue](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1303) for more details

Try with

```
yarn upgrade webpack-dev-server@^2.11.1
```